# Django server does not accept cookies

Tags: django, nginx, csrf, django-csrf, django-cors-headers

When I try to send a POST request to the DJANGO app hosted on the server, with included credentials in the Axios request or with a Postman app, I cannot access cookies in the app, because cookies are never sent.

Axios config looks like this:

```
export function genericApiHost(host: string) {
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Accept: "application/json",
    // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
  };
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: `${host}`,
    headers: headers,
    withCredentials: true,
  });
}
```

If I include the allow origin header I get a CORS error, otherwise, cookies are not sent.

This is part of the Django app settings:

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['*']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]
```

**With the settings I listed here, the application works correctly locally, but when the code is uploaded to the nginx server, it doesn't work**

Comment: What cookie do you want? The `csrftoken` ?  Where is the Django part that send the cookies to the client ?

Comment: Please share the full error message, not just "CORS Error"

Comment: _Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response._ @Zatigem

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, it seems that you are having trouble accessing cookies in your Django app when sending a POST request with credentials. You mentioned that cookies are never sent, and you cannot access them. You also mentioned that if you include the allow origin header, you get a CORS error, and if you don't include it, cookies are not sent.

You have set `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS` and `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS` to `True`, and `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE`, `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`, `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`, and `ALLOWED_HOSTS` to `False`, `False`, `['*']`, and `["*"]`, respectively. These settings work correctly locally, but when you upload the code to the nginx server, it doesn't work.

Based on your description, it seems that you are facing a **CORS issue**. The error message you mentioned indicates that the browser is blocking the cookie because of the SameSite attribute. This attribute is set to Lax by default, which prevents the cookie from being sent in a cross-site request. To resolve this issue, you need to update the attributes of the cookie. Here is an example of how to set the cookie in Django:

```py
response.set_cookie(
    key='csrftoken',
    value=request.META['CSRF_COOKIE'],
    expires=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME'],
    path=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_PATH'],
    secure=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE'],
    httponly=False,
    samesite='Lax'
)
```

You can also try setting `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE` and `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` to `True` in your Django app settings. Additionally, you may want to check if your server has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set. If not, you can add it to your server configuration to allow cross-origin requests.

Comment: No need to repeat the question's details in your answer

Comment: @Zatigem Repeating (part of) the question is one characteristic of AI-generated responses.